# What is the exactly use of defaultFs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop, I find the defaultFs in `core-site.xml`, according to official definition:

`the default path prefix used by the Hadoop FS client when none is given`

Could anybody explain a little bit more about it?

For example I use a hdfs Java API in local, I guess I am the client, so does it only used in setting the connect address like `"hdfs://defaultFsAddress:8020/`, any other usage of it?

Answer (score 3):

> The name of the default file system. A URI whose scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.

Default value: `file:///`

---

Its default value is the local filesystem, so changing it to `hdfs://<address>:<port>/` will specify that you are connecting to HDFS instead.

For example,

```
hdfs dfs -ls /
```

would initially show the local root filesystem without changing the value. HDFS is a file abstraction over a cluster, so its root is not the same as the local system's. You need to change the value in order to create the distributed file system.

You can see all other [core-site defaults here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml).

Answer (score 1):

fs.defaultFS in core-site.xml - gives the datanode address of namenode.

Datanode looks for the address here for the namenode and tries to contact it using RPC.